# Convergence of Compactly Supported $C^{\infty}$ Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, distribution-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an open set, and define  $\mathcal{D}(\Omega)=C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ with compact support in $\Omega$ and notion of convergence as follows:
$\phi_{m}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ converges to $ \phi\in C_{c}^{\infty} (\Omega)$ if there exists a compact set $K\subset\Omega$ such that $\left(\operatorname{supp}(\phi_{m})-\operatorname{supp}(\phi)\right)\subset K,$ and $\phi_{m},$ along with its derivatives of all orders, converges to $\phi\in K.$

My question is how do I show that the following sequences of standard mollifiers converge in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}),$ if they converge at all:

\begin{align}
&(i)& j_n(x)&=j\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)\\
&(ii)&j_n(x)&=\sqrt{n}\,j(nx)
\end{align}

It turns out that (ii) converges to $0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ yet not in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}),$ but I'm not able to show this rigorously.

Comment: You did not specify $j$, I guess it is a fixed test function (perhaps, additionally positive with integral $1$). The supports in $(i)$ are contained in a fixed compact set and $j_n^{(\alpha)}(x)=j^{(\alpha)}(x+1/n)$ converge uniformly to $j^{(\alpha)}$. In $(ii)$ you do not even have convergence for $x=0$ if $j(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @Jochen Take the concrete example of a standard mollifier from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier